# How do you make a transparent glass material in Blender 3.2?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, eevee-render-engine, glass

I've looked everywhere but answers I've found are not applicable to my version of Blender because a ton of settings seem to change or disappear with every new version.

I just want to make a transparent glass object in **Blender** using either **Eevee** or **Cycles**.

I used to use Blender several hours a day and totally stopped after v2.8/v3 changed everything and made the app unusable without spending more hours relearning everything. Now I can't even make a glass material.

I tried using **Fresnel / Refraction / Glossy** with a **Mix Shader**. I tried using the **Glass shader**. I tried using the Principled BDSF. Nothing works my object stays gray and opaque whatever I do. I'll probably go do this project in 2.7 but for next time I'd love to know how.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Cycles, a simple Glass BSDF is probably the best bet. If the object looks too "plain" (in rendered mode), I recommend using an HDRI for the world (environment) lighting.

[Glass BSDF with HDRI Lighting]:

[image: Glass1]

Alternatively, if you are using EEVEE, the regular Glass BSDF doesn't work so well, so you can approximate glass with this shader below. Don't forget to change your materials Blend Mode to something other than *Opaque*:

[image: Glass2]

Comment: Tried your node setup, it's not working. https://imgur.com/a/nhL0Cmf - even the sphere in preview doesn't have transparency. I'd rather get to the goal I have without having to set up HDR lighting to keep my workflow simple and avoid weird looking reflections.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm misunderstanding. Your issue is that even with a glass shader all you see is see a grey box? If you put something behind the box, there is still no transparency (you can't see it behind)?

Comment: @MicroMachine The sphere preview looks like you have the _Blend Mode_ in your material still set to _Opaque_. Read the answer carefully, it says: "_Don't forget to change your materials Blend Mode to something **other** than Opaque_". So maybe try _Alpha Blend_. What I can't see in your screenshot: have you assigned the new material to any faces or have you just added it to the object? If it's not assigned to any faces in _Edit Mode_, they all use the first material. And about no HDRI lighting: well, a grey background will make glass always look boring. You need reflections etc.

Comment: Oh, and in _Eevee_ don't forget to set a _Refraction Depth_ in the material settings. In the question you said you wanted to make a glass object using either _Eevee_ or _Cycles_, when you say the node setup didn't work for you, did you mean both or just _Eevee_?

Comment: Also, the sphere in the preview becomes transparent only when "Screen Space Refractions" is enabled in the material settings.

Comment: Yes, I couldn't see anything behind the box. The problem was for both Eevee and Cycles. Changing the Blend Mode to Alpha Blend worked - I overlooked that part of the answer. Thanks for all the tips!